# Formula error in user defined function for finding the side of a triangle

Tags: python

It shows a syntax error for the alpha section of the UD function.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vaiH3.png)

```
import math

def getC(a, b, alpha):
    form_ula = (math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2) - (2 * a * b * cos alpha)) 
    return form_ula
```

Comment: Please use the code formatter in your questions for easier viewing in addition to a formatted stack trace

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you aren't passing alpha to the cos function (should be `cos(alpha)`)

in addition you can simply return the first line:

```
def getC(a, b, alpha):
    return math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2) - (2 * a * b * math.cos(alpha))
```

Answer (score 1):

It should be `math.cos(alpha)))` instead of `cos alpha))`. It's just a syntax error. You can look at the error details in your editor to identify such errors.

```
import math
def getC(a, b, alpha):
    form_ula = (math.pow(a, 2) + math.pow(b, 2) - (2 * a * b * math.cos(alpha)))
    return form_ula
```